# Using optim for maximisation

Tags: r, optimization

The help page, `?optim` states that:

1. control 
   a list of control parameters. See ‘Details’.
2. By default optim performs minimization, but it will maximize if control$fnscale is negative.
3. fnscale
   An overall scaling to be applied to the value of fn and gr during optimization. If negative, turns the problem into a maximization problem. Optimization is performed on fn(par)/fnscale.

Does this mean that

```
optim(par = par, fn = fn, dat = dat, hessian = TRUE, method= "BFGS", control = list(fnscale = -1))
```

Will maximise function `fn`?

Comment: yes, try `-x^2+1` to be convinced